# Why IOCP is used?

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, iocp, overlapped-io

I am trying to understand why IOCP is used. I can think of two reasons:

- Since `WSARecv()` will not block, then I can handle 1000s of clients without having to create a new thread for each client (also, there is a limit on how many threads you can create, and so the number of clients you can handle will be limited).
- Since `WSASend()` will not block, then when I want to send a large file, I don't have to create a new thread to send it (if I did not create a new thread then the UI thread will block of course).

What other reasons are there to use IOCP?

Comment: Sure, not having thousands of threads waiting on I/O completion is the point.  That does not scale, threads are too expensive.

Answer (score 2):

IOCP has the benefits that you mention but that is not exclusive to IOCP. I'm not that familiar with the native socket APIs but some Win32 APIs have "overlapped IO" which is asynchronous but does not require IOCP.

Another benefit is that with IOCP the number of request serving threads is (kind of) optimized by the kernel. The kernel is aware of all blocking that request serving threads do and it will see to it that there are enough, and not more, threads unblocked at all times so that the CPU is well-utilized. Ideally, you would never block and there would be as many threads as there are cores (assuming 100% load). That would be very efficient.

IOCP also helps to reduce context switching because instead of switching to another thread to process the results of an IO an existing thread that is busy already simply calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` again.

`GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx` can be used to reduce the number of transitions to the kernel because you can dequeue multiple IOs in one call.

Comment: In fact, **all** I/O on Windows is asynchronous, as far as the kernel is concerned. The synchronous versions are provided as a convenience. More information is available at [I know that an overlapped file handle requires an lpOverlapped, but why does it (sometimes) work if I omit it?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/04/11/10292442.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Also, it cuts down on avoidable bulk data copying and protection ring cycles.  Instead of the kernel having to copy data from the network stack buffers into a user-space buffer when requested by a recv() call, user-space buffers are supplied by WSARecv() and the stack can then load them directly in kernel space.